# Navbar Responsive

Tags: flexbox, navbar, responsive

Just in need of a little help to finish this, or at least illuminate.
The menu is not collapsing into the burger menu for me.
I've incuded a link to the codepen here :

https://codepen.io/musicstuffed/pen/eYYoZjK

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbarToggle {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;

    }
    .active {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .mainNav {


    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the changes I made to the codepen you provided. [Link](https://codepen.io/musicstuffed/pen/eYYoZjK)

Basically you hide the navigation on mobile devices and display it only when it's active:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .navbarToggle {
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;  
  }
  .mainNav {
    display: none;
  }
  .active {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the css layout you want to achieve and if not this can easily be changed.